# Written code in php and saving data in myphpadmin, data does't save into database nor it is any error

Tags: php, mysql

I have written the code below to same simple data into my SQL. It is doing everything correct except data is not saved to database.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')    {
    $ename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['ename']);
    $enumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['enumber']);
    $eemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['eemail']);
    $eproperty = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['eproperty']);
    $emessage = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['emessage']);
    $status = "OK";
    $msg="";                                                        
    if ($status=="OK") {
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"insert into enquiry (ename, enumber, eemail, eproperty, emessage) values('$ename', '$enumber', '$eemail', '$eproperty', $'emessage')");
        print "<div class='alert alert-success'>Your property enquiry has been submitted successfully.</div>";
    } else { 
        $errormsg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
            <i class='fa fa-ban-circle'></i><strong>Please Fix Below Errors : </br></strong>".$msg."</div>"; //printing error if found in validation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is open to `SQL injections`, use prepared statement. And the error is here:

```
values('$ename', '$enumber', '$eemail', '$eproperty', $'emessage')");
```

here typo at  `$'emessage'`, so change it to:

```
'$emessage'
```

Answer (score 0):

The last message variable is not properly added

```
$query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into enquiry (ename, enumber, eemail, eproperty, emessage) values('$ename', '$enumber', '$eemail', '$eproperty', '$emessage')");//quote should be before variable itself
```

Your code is very vulnerable to sql injections. Take advantage of prepared statements using mysqli procedural style as you are using that

Using prepared statements,

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO enquiry (ename,enumber,eemail,eproperty,emessage) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");//bind parameter to prevent sql injection 

$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $ename,$enumber, $eemail,$eproperty,$emessage); 

if($stmt->execute() === true) {
echo 'enquiry saved'; 
} else {
echo 'error'. $stmt->error; 
}
```